# Create a new map from an array of object with similar id in Typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm trying to create a map> from a list of objects that have similar ids in typescript, but I don't get the correct way to do. I know that in lodash something like so is doable but can't get it to work. This what I have tried

let's say I have list of colors like so:

```
 [
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "color": "red",
        "ref": "tr"
    },
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "color": "blue",
        "ref": "gt",
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "color": "red",
        "ref": "tt"
    },
 ]
```

I'm trying to construct a map like so

```
[
  1: [
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "color": "red",
        "ref": "tr"
      },
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "color": "blue",
        "ref": "gt",
      }
     ],
  2: [
      {
        "Id": "2",
        "color": "red",
        "ref": "tt"
      }
     ]
]
```

this is what I tried so far:

```
const colorsMap: Map<string, Array<Color>> = new Map<string, Array<Color>>();
let colorLists: Array<Color> = [];
colors.forEach(function (value, i) {
            if (value[i - 1]) {
                if (colors[i - 1].id=== value.gblId) {
                    const color = new Color(value.styleId, value.color, value.ref);
                    colorLists.push(gblRowValue);
                } else {
                    const color = new Color(value.styleId, value.color, value.ref);
                    colorLists= new Array<Color>();
                    colorLists.push(color);
                }
            }
            colorsMap.set(value.id, colorLists);
        });
```

The result is in each array I get only one value:

```
    [
      1: [
          {
           "Id": "1",
           "color": "blue",
           "ref": "gt",
          }
         ],
      2: [
          {
           "Id": "2",
           "color": "red",
           "ref": "tt"
          }
         ]
     ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you can use es6 features, you could use the following small snippet, which does not require the huge lodash library:

```js
let colors = [
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "color": "red",
        "ref": "tr"
    },
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "color": "blue",
        "ref": "gt",
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "color": "red",
        "ref": "tt"
    },
];
 
let orderedColors = colors.reduce((returnArray, color) => {
     if(!returnArray[color.Id]){
        returnArray[color.Id] = [];   
     }
     returnArray[color.Id].push(color);
     return returnArray;
 },[]);
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that you can import individual lodash functions if you don't want to import the whole library.

Comment: @GruffBunny still would prefer to use "native" es6 instead of importing some library code, right ;)

Comment: Not if it's a one liner like `_.groupBy(data, 'Id');` :)

Comment: Well the lodash groupBy function also uses reduce, but brings it's own polyfill, which you would not need if you can support es6 natively! Just some bytes but maybe one dependency less ^^

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/groupBy.js

Comment: And you could wrap this code into a own group by function :D

Comment: @MarcWissler works like a charm tkx. I agree I prefer to know what I'm doing rather than using a library. Although I agree with GruffBunny lodash have worked hard to optimize code and reduce verbosity

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash's [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) to achieve that result:

```js
const data = [{"Id":"1","color":"red","ref":"tr"},{"Id":"1","color":"blue","ref":"gt"},{"Id":"2","color":"red","ref":"tt"}];

const result = _.groupBy(data, 'Id');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) provides three parameters to the callback.

> `currentValue`
>
> The value of the current element being processed in the array.
>
> `index`
>
> The index of the current element being processed in the array.
>
> `array`
>
> The array that forEach() is being applied to.

You're using `value` and `i`, which are `currentValue` and `index`.

So `if (value[i - 1]) {` means `if (currentValue[index - 1]) {` which doesn't make much sense to me.

I think you just want to use the `currentValue`, something like this.

```
interface Color {
  Id: string;
  color: string;
  ref: string;
};

let colors: Color[] = [{
  "Id": "1",
  "color": "red",
  "ref": "tr"
},
{
  "Id": "1",
  "color": "blue",
  "ref": "gt",
},
{
  "Id": "2",
  "color": "red",
  "ref": "tt"
}];

let colorMap = new Map<string, Color[]>();

colors.forEach((color) => {
    let colorsArray = colorMap.get(color.Id) || [];
    colorsArray.push(color);

    colorMap.set(color.Id, colorsArray)
});

let colorId1Index0 = colorMap.get("1")[0];
let colorId1Index1 = colorMap.get("1")[1];
let colorId2Index0 = colorMap.get("2")[0];

console.log(`${colorId1Index0.color} ${colorId1Index0.ref}`);
console.log(`${colorId1Index1.color} ${colorId1Index1.ref}`);
console.log(`${colorId2Index0.color} ${colorId2Index0.ref}`);
```

The console logs:

```
red tr
blue gt
red tt
```

Here's it working on the [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Color%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20color%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20ref%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20colors%3A%20Color%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22Id%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22red%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22ref%22%3A%20%22tr%22%0D%0A%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22Id%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22blue%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22ref%22%3A%20%22gt%22%2C%0D%0A%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22Id%22%3A%20%222%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22color%22%3A%20%22red%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22ref%22%3A%20%22tt%22%0D%0A%7D%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20colorMap%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20Color%5B%5D%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Acolors.forEach((color)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20colorsArray%20%3D%20colorMap.get(color.Id)%20%7C%7C%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20colorsArray.push(color)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20colorMap.set(color.Id%2C%20colorsArray)%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20colorId1Index0%20%3D%20colorMap.get(%221%22)%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20colorId1Index1%20%3D%20colorMap.get(%221%22)%5B1%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20colorId2Index0%20%3D%20colorMap.get(%222%22)%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60%24%7BcolorId1Index0.color%7D%20%24%7BcolorId1Index0.ref%7D%60)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60%24%7BcolorId1Index1.color%7D%20%24%7BcolorId1Index1.ref%7D%60)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60%24%7BcolorId2Index0.color%7D%20%24%7BcolorId2Index0.ref%7D%60)%3B).